# Missing custom Inventor materials in SVF/SVF2 models using Autodesk FORGE Model Derivative

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

A customer has created a custom Inventor Material Library: all his parts are defined to use these custom materials in order to obtain a very realistic representation of model.

When I try to convert his assembly files (exported with Pack & Go) with Autodesk FORGE Model Derivative, the output models (no different between SVF and SVF2 format) contains some white surfaces associated to the parts defined with custom materials.

Interessant: in developer console of browser I've found an error HTTP 400 related to the *Galvinized_2_svf_tex_mod.png*.

What can I do in order to obtain a better SVF model?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the cause: see [Appearances with enabled Self-Illumination are translated to white when creating a shared view from Inventor](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Appearances-with-enabled-Self-Illumination-are-translated-to-white-when-creating-a-shared-view-from-Inventor.html)

The Material Library of customer has the "Self Illumination" active!

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue. I removed the "Self Illumination" and the color came through. I then added "Self Illumination" back to the color, but added the assembly file to my zip with copy and paste in leu of Pack and Go. And the color still works in the viewer.

Don't know if that always works, but if anyone else needs SI, it might be worth a try.

P.S. Good to know that shared views can be a quick test of the Viewer. Hadn't thought of that before.